# Thread abort while making HTTP Get Request

Tags: c#, .net, threadabortexception

Recently I have started receiving alerts with the following stack trace:

> Message:  Thread was being aborted.
>
> Stack Trace:  at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean
>   async, HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)  at
>   System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean onSubmitThread,
>   HttpWebRequest request, TriState needReConnect)  at
>   System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   forcedsubmit)  at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest
>   request, String connName)  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)  at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()  at
>   *removed to protect identity*

It seems to me that the thread is aborted before the actual connection is made with the remote server. Is that true? Why would such a situation occur - trying to narrow down the problem.

I tried looking for documentation on the `System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection` method and couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Adding a structure of the calling code in response to comments.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = method; request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Headers.Add("Foo", "Bar");
request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

UPDATE 2: This alert only occurs sporadically for a few minutes and then goes away.

UPDATE 3: An essential piece of information I hadn't provided yet - The piece of code I displayed in UPDATE 1 is being called by a task which is on a timer.

Comment: What does the (relevant) bit of code that causes this exception look like?

Comment: Apologies! I managed to hit 'post' before I finished typing out the content. I've filled out the content of the question now.

Comment: Second, in what kind of project / context do you execute that code? ASP.NET? Console application? WPF or Windows Forms application?

Comment: The calling code is part of an ASMX (SOAP) service. It is a method that uses a service client to make an HTTP GET call. The SOAP service is called on a schedule and it in turn makes the HTTP GET call.

Comment: @ArxoClay I think they want to see the actual code, not have you describe it :)

Comment: Things like this happen when the service call ends while an asynchronous operation is still happening.  Be aware of stuff like: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Please show the code that is calling the code you posted. The problem is in **the way you are starting that block of code**, not the code itself.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Could I have a little more context so that I can answer that question better? Do you think the way the request is created might be problematic?

Comment: I would put money the code you posted is being run inside a `Task` or a `Thread`. Your ASMX page completes its response before that task or thread is complete. IIS shuts down the AppDomain that was running your code (including your background process that has not finished yet) you get the error you got. This is all guesses because you have not shown your code, that is why I have not posted as an answer. Please read the post [Moby Disk linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905396/thread-abort-while-making-http-get-request?noredirect=1#comment47934426_29905396) it goes in to more detail

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: You are correct about the code I've written up being called by a task on a timer. The interesting thing is the IdleTimeout has been set to 0 to prevent IIS "pulling the rug" on the app domain. But based on the article you and Moby Disk have alluded to, it appears IIS does that for a myriad of reasons (not just timeouts), correct?

Comment: @ArxoClay Yes, the timeout is only one of many reasons the app pool could be re-cycled.

Comment: This can be caused by `Response.Redirect`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Moby Disk and @Scott Chamberlain for helping me solve this issue.

This issue was caused because the application pool hosting the code I've written up had a *Recycling* setting with *Regular Time Interval (minutes)* set to *1740* minutes which equates to *29* hours (the default).

Whenever the worker thread was running during such a recycle, I would see the error (because it would receive a ThreadAbort exception which it didn't handle).
Fixing the setting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem before and usually this is an indication that either the code around calling the service through your client or the service itself is calling `Thread.Abort()` (which is bad practice, but is used to mitigate the fact that connections can remain stuck open on the server). `ThreadAbortExceptions` in service calls primarily occur when the thread is explicitly being told to abort.

I should add that if the server is aborting the thread, you'll usually get it back as a `SoapException`. So check your codebase for usages of `Thread.Abort()`.

Comment: He is using ASP.NET which aborts all threads when shutting down the service.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain but he's not hosting the service?

Comment: He is, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905396/thread-abort-while-making-http-get-request/29905699?noredirect=1#comment47933748_29905396) the code is being run inside a IIS ASMX instance. IIS is the one calling Abort.